# On a condition for a.s. finite stopping times

Tags: probability-theory, stopping-times

Assume that $\{\tau_n: n \in \mathbb{N}\} $ is a sequence of stopping times with respect to some filtration such that $P[\tau_n < \infty] = 1. $ Is that true that there must exist a sequence of constants $\{m_n: n \in \mathbb{N}\} \in \mathbb{R}_+ $ such that 
$$ P[\tau_n > m_n] \to 0 $$
as $n \to \infty$?

I realize that this is clearly true for the case in which one deals with a single finite stopping time, $\tau, $ but for a general sequence? 
Thank you in advance for any help.

Maurice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each non-negative random variable $X$ such that $\mathbb P\{X\lt+\infty\}=1$, we have $\lim_{R\to +\infty}\mathbb P\{X\gt R\}=0$. 
With this argument, for each $n$, you can choose $m_n$ such that $\mathbb P\{\tau_n\gt m_n\}\lt 1/n$.